# String list get an item starting without loop

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have a array list contains thousands of data.

For Example:

```
List<String> custNames = new ArrayList<String>();
custNames.add("John");
custNames.add("Tom");
custNames.add("Bart");
custNames.add("Tim");
custNames.add("Broad");
```

Now I want to get count of names only starting with 'T'. I used looping mechanism for my solution.

```
List<String> filterNames = new ArrayList<String>();
String nameStarts="T";
for(int i=0;i<custNames.size();i++)
{
    if(custNames.get(i).toLowerCase().startsWith(nameStarts.toLowerCase()))
    {
        filterNames.add(custNames.get(i));
    }
}
System.out.println(filterNames.size());
```

But I have very large collection of data in this custNames list.
Is there any different solution without using loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is very good solution from Java 8 for your problem.

Try this,

```
long filterNameCount = custNames
        .stream()
        .parallel() 
        .filter((s) -> s.startsWith(nameStarts.toLowerCase()))
        .count();

System.out.println(filterNameCount);
```

Comment: using .stream().parallel() get significant performance improvement

Comment: be very, very careful about that.  If your input is not super big, using parallel() will actively hurt performance and make code slower.

Comment: I think you are missing a .map(String::toLowerCase) after the call to .parallel()

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to using a third-party library, there are a few interesting options you could use with [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

If you use the `ArrayList` as you have it above, you can use the `LazyIterate` utility as follows:

```
int count = LazyIterate.collect(custNames, String::toLowerCase)
        .countWith(String::startsWith, nameStarts.toLowerCase());
Assert.assertEquals(2, count);
```

If you use the Eclipse Collections replacement for `ArrayList`, you can use the rich functional protocols available directly on `MutableList`:

```
MutableList<String> custNames =
        Lists.mutable.with("John", "Tom", "Bart", "Tim", "Broad");
String nameStarts= "T";
int count = custNames.asLazy()
        .collect(String::toLowerCase)
        .countWith(String::startsWith, nameStarts.toLowerCase());
System.out.println(count);
Assert.assertEquals(2, count);
```

The serial API in Eclipse Collections is eager-by-default, which is why I called `asLazy()` first.  The collect method would otherwise create another `MutableList`.

If you benchmark your code with your full set of data, the following parallel version of the code may be more performant:

```
MutableList<String> custNames =
        Lists.mutable.with("John", "Tom", "Bart", "Tim", "Broad");
String nameStarts= "T";
int processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
int batchSize = Math.max(1, custNames.size() / processors);
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(processors);
int count = custNames.asParallel(executor, batchSize)
        .collect(String::toLowerCase)
        .countWith(String::startsWith, nameStarts.toLowerCase());
executor.shutdown();
Assert.assertEquals(2, count);
```

The `asParallel()` API in Eclipse Collections is lazy-by-default.  The API forces you to pass in a an `ExecutorService` and an `int` batchSize.  This gives you complete control over the parallelism.

You can also use the Stream API with all `MutableCollections` in Eclipse Collections because they extend `java.util.Collection`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a tree storage : it would very efficient for this kind of search. If you are stucked with a list the   previous answered is a way to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more or less static list and perform search operation often you can sort your list or use TreeMap.

Also you don't need to create new list and get its size then. You can simply create a counter variable and increment it.

Answer (score 0):

remove all the items which dont start with "T" like this:

```
custNames.removeIf(p->!p.startsWith("T"));
```

you can make a copy out of your list and remove items not starting with "T".

Answer (score 0):

First, you can shorten your initialization with `Arrays.asList(T)`; Second, I would use a simple loop to build a table of counts **once** and then use that to determine the subsequent queries. Something like,

```
List<String> custNames = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("John", "Tom", 
        "Bart", "Tim", "Broad"));
int[] counts = new int[26];
for (String name : custNames) {
    char ch = Character.toLowerCase(name.charAt(0));
    counts[ch - 'a']++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > 0) {
        System.out.printf("There are %d words that start with %c%n", 
                counts[i], (char) ('a' + i));
    }
}
```

Which outputs

```
There are 2 words that start with b
There are 1 words that start with j
There are 2 words that start with t
```

Or, in the specific case - `counts['t' - 'a']` is the count of words starting with `t`.

Answer (score 0):

If the order in which the items are stored does not matter, you could store the names in a HashMap, where the first character of each name is the key, and an ArrayList of names with that first character are the values. And then all you need to do, assuming the HashMap is named customerList, is customerList.get("T").size().

**Initializing HashList and Adding Customers**

```
HashMap<Character, ArrayList<String>> customerList = new HashMap<Character, ArrayList<String>>();
int NUM_ALPHABETS = 26;
int ascii_char = 97;
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_ALPHABETS; i++){
  char c = (char) ascii_char;
  customerList.add(c, new ArrayList<String>());
  ascii_char++;
}

customerList.get("t").add("Tony");
customerList.get("a").add("Alice");
customerList.get("b").add("Ben");
```

**Getting Number of Customers Starting with "t"**

```
 int num_t = customerList.get("t").size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own sorting and finding implementation.

Consider the following:

```
public class ContainingArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    private Comparator<E> comparator;

    public ContainingArrayList(Comparator<E> comparator) {
        this.setComparator(comparator);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        // If the collection is empty or the new element is bigger than the last one, append it to the end of the collection
        if(size() == 0 || comparator.compare(e, get(size()-1)) >= 0)
            return super.add(e);
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
                int result = comparator.compare(e, get(i));
                // If the new element is bigger than the current element, continue with the next element
                if (result > 0) continue;
                // If the new element is equal to the current element, no need to insert (you might insert of course)
                if (result == 0) return false;
                // Otherwise the new element is smaller than the current element, so insert it between the previous and the current element
                super.add(i, e);
                return true;
            }
            return super.add(e);
        }
    }

    public E get(E containingElement) {
        int start = 0;
        int end = size()-1;
        // If the element is the first one, return the first element
        if(comparator.compare(containingElement, super.get(start)) == 0)
            return super.get(start);
        // If the element is the last one, return the last element
        if(comparator.compare(containingElement, super.get(end)) == 0)
            return super.get(end);

        // Otherwise do a binary search
        while(start != end) {
            // Get the element between start and end positions
            E mid = super.get(start + (end/2));
            // Compare the two elements
            int result = comparator.compare(containingElement, mid);
            // If the middle element compared to the containing element is equal, return the middle element
            if(result == 0) {
                return mid;
            }
            // If the containing element is smaller than the middle, halve the end position
            else if(result < 0) {
                end = start + (end/2);
            }
            // If the containing element is bigger than the middle, set the start position to the middle position
            else if(result > 0) {
                start = start + (end/2);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public Comparator<E> getComparator() {
        return comparator;
    }

    public void setComparator(Comparator<E> comparator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }
}
```

The custom comparator is used to sort the elements and to find the element that starts with a specific character. This means that you can change the comparator implementation for your needs at any time or you can create a more dynamic finding solution.

Test:

```
public class SortFindTest {

    public SortFindTest() {
        ContainingArrayList<String> t = new ContainingArrayList<String>(new MyComparator());
        t.add("John");
        t.add("Tom");
        t.add("Bart");
        t.add("Tim");
        t.add("Broad");

        System.out.println(t.get("T"));
    }

    class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            int o1c = o1.charAt(0);
            int o2c = o2.charAt(0);
            if(o1c == o2c)
                return 0;
            if(o1c > o2c)
                return 1;
            return -1;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SortFindTest();
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this would be faster than Java 8 Stream API but it worth a try.